# Help identifying chords/scale

Tags: chords, scales, melody, digital-piano, electronic-music

I'm new to music theory and I am trying to reproduce parts of a song for practice. I really like the chords/scale that kick in at 2:36 of this song:

Open Form - Lost Desert, Amand, Reigan:
https://open.spotify.com/track/3hJ0na7qww6vU36mNBBquI?si=3232296b13d248f3

If you ignore the effects, you'll notice that there is some underlining chords/scale forming a melody on a 32 beat loop.

Any chance someone here would know? Any help is appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: If you're asking us to transcribe the recording, that's off-topic on Music SE. If you're asking about something else, please be more specific.

Comment: Did you listen to the song starting at 2:36? There's a piano scale that goes on for 32 beats. I want to know what chords are being used. There's some chance that it's a popular chord progression. I just don't know enough to identify it by ear.